# Using google-api-javascript-client with node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-client

Google's client JS library for its APIs is : https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted

I was wondering if there was any way I could use this with node.js

(I'm writing a small app that uses the google calendar api. I'm very new to node.js)

Answer (score 2):

Google has a node.js client library for its APIs: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
googleapis.discover('calendar', 'v3').execute(function(err, client) {
  // authenticate and make requests here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The js client supports [promise](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/10/promises-in-google-apis-javascript.html). While the node client does not, as [wont fix](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/197).

For me, it is a big feature difference. With promise, the code can be written in the generators way to avoid the callback hell.